# ¿Comó itero un Json en angularjs, pero solo para obtener un elemento de distintos nodos?

Tags: base-de-datos, angular

Tengo una duda, como puedo iterar un Json que proviene de Firebase, pero lo que necesito es obtener varios elementos de varios nodos de todo un Json, por ejemplo tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener todos los elementos "depto" de todo el nodo "condomino"? o existe alguna sentencia tipo "select depto from condomino" para obtener esos datos? (Pero con sintaxis de angular) Soy nuevo con firebase y angular, espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos y Gracias.

Comment: puedes hacer un ***ngFor** para obtenes los depto de cada nodo y agregar el **index** al *ngFor

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero necesito obtener esos datos en el BackEnd no en el Front, porque luego debo agrupar todos los deptos que inicien con "A" luego los que inicien con "B". Saludos y Gracias.